# How to transparent black color in camera swift

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to make the black bars at top as well as bottom in camera transparent. How do I make it transparent:
[image: this is my camera]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new UIView which is black color and view width-height will be same to old view with transparent and your old view color should be clear and alpha 1 hope u get solution from this ....